# JoinColumns on column and static value

Tags: php, doctrine, sonata-admin, sonata

I have two tables in my sonata-admin setup with Symfony2: `'product'` and `'product_description'`. The second one holds descriptions of the products in several languages and defines the product_id and language_id columns as compound primary key. In the product table there is no `language_id` column so that it should be dynamically joined with the description depending on the language the customer chose.

I am currently trying to join them by the help of a `OneToOne` and `JoinColumns` annotation, however how can `product_description` be joined with the `language_id` as a static value (which is not present as a column in product table)?

```
/**
* ProductDescription
*
* @ORM\Table(name="product_description")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProductDescription
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $productId;

/*
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="language_id", type="boolean")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $languageId;

....

}



/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
private $productId;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ProductDescription")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *      @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="product_id"),
 *      @JoinColumn(name="??????", referencedColumnName="language_id")
 * })
 */
private $productDescription;

....

}
```

edit: more code added

```
// admin class
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{       
    $listMapper->addIdentifier('productId', 'integer')
        ->addIdentifier('productDescription.productName');
}

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{   
    $formMapper->add('offersId', 'integer', array('read_only' => true))
        ->add('productDescription.productName');
}
```

I tried to join it by hand with queryBuilder in createQuery() method however will give weird results in list view.

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);

    $query->addSelect('p')->innerJoin('AppBundle\Entity\ProductDescription', 'p', 'WITH', $query->getRootAlias().'.productId = p.productId and p.languageId = 2');

    return $query;
}
```

edit: Here is a similar question in Hibernate - maybe transferable to doctrine?

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=986966

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Code added, how to join those two tables on product_id and a static value for language_id, say 2.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, no "language" exists in your model, so you cannot create relation to any. What you can do is just create a string or integer column type and just keep your language value in it:

```
 /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="string")
  * @var string
  */
 private $languageId
```

You can use your session locale or have some constant in your model with some validation of valid ID:

```
const LANGUAGE_ID_EN = 'en';
const LANGUAGE_ID_FR = 'fr';

public function setLanguageId($languageId)
{
    if ( ! in_array($$languageId, [...]) {
        throw new \Exception(...);
    }

    $this->languageId = $languageId;
}
```

Then you just make queries with additional WHERE clause:

```
WHERE language_id = ?
```

I hope I got you right. Let us know if your goal is something different.

Comment: Yes, you understood me correctly, however I am using sonata-admin which does not offer a possibility to declare an own SQL statement. So I am looking for a solution with the JoinColumns annotation only.

Comment: Please, specify the situation you are going to use join. Which controller/method/case exactly you need such relation? Then it would be easier to think of a solution. Sonata Admin, as many other bundles or "good architecture" components allow to inject custom things, we just need to understand where exactly to do it, as methods might vary. PS. And Join is a model relation, so there CANNOT BE such solution. Get to know more on databases and Doctrine to understand the impossibility of your will. ;)

Comment: I am very in databases however symfony as well as doctrine is quite new for me ;) I simply cannot understand why there is no possibility to use just a static value in a JoinColumn annotation. What is the reason for always having to provide an existing column in both database entities? For my use case this is not very handy! And as you seem to have understood my problem, could you give just an example how this scenario would be handled in a sonata-admin environment? I would just need a sample how to do, no need to adapt everything to my controllers/methods etc.

Comment: OK, let's be constructive. 1. As I mentioned before, PROVIDE situation, where you need such join in Sonata. Is it in Admin class? Is it in List/Edit view? Is it to render field? What and where exactly do you need to have a query with such a join? 2. If I got you right, I ALREADY gave you THE BEST solution. You haven't provided any arguments, WHY this solution is not for you. 3. If you are asking, why there can't be a join to some static value, I bet, you don't really understand how databases and relation work, so try to read some basics on "Database relations", I guess?!

Comment: PS. This is stackoverflow. You have a problem, we are trying to help you. Please, be more respectful and help us help you. Be more specific, provide code, describe case/situation (with code examples as well) etc. This way we can help you better and faster. And not having this pointless/almost personal chat.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to be rude in any way. According your questions: 1. Yes in an Admin class. 2. List view as well as edit view. 3. It seems that doctrine does not (yet) support that kind of join situation using just annotations, see https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3540#event-483907334 I currently tried to join the productDescription table in the createQuery() function by queryBuilder but this gives weird results in list view.